# iMac Pro crashing repetitively, Kernel Panics

Tags: imac, crash, kernel-panic

I've been encountering kernel panics regularly ever since I upgraded to macOS Big Sur 11.3 on my iMac Pro late-2015. Here is the panic log.

```
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000000c0a
 family: 6 model: 94 stepping: 3 microcode: 226
 signature: 0x506e3
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600 CPU @ 3.30GHz
 10 error-reporting banks
Processor 1: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC0_STATUS(0x401): 0xf600018000040150
 IA32_MC0_ADDR(0x402):   0x00007fff3446957f
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out on cpu 1, NMI-ing
mp_kdp_enter() NMI pending on cpus: 0 2 3
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out during locked wait after NMI;expected 4 acks but received 1 after 9079152 loops in 1656000000 ticks
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff800a5c5ed9): "Machine Check at 0x00007fff34469582, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x000000010e7cf1bc, CR3: 0x000000025c30b04f, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0\n" "RAX: 0x000000010e7cf000, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000000000006, RDX: 0x00007fff204ddb00\n" "RSP: 0x000070000587b8a0, RBP: 0x000070000587c650, RSI: 0x000000000000006f, RDI: 0x000000000008a787\n" "R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0xffffffff00000000, R10: 0x00007fd83c81dc98, R11: 0x0000000000000206\n" "R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x00007fd83c81d400, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000246, RIP: 0x00007fff34469582, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/2288acc43c/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-7195.101.1/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa09549bba0 : 0xffffff800a48e02d 
0xffffffa09549bbf0 : 0xffffff800a5d48e3 
0xffffffa09549bc30 : 0xffffff800a5c4eda 
0xffffffa09549bc80 : 0xffffff800a432a2f 
0xffffffa09549bca0 : 0xffffff800a48d84d 
0xffffffa09549bdc0 : 0xffffff800a48db43 
0xffffffa09549be30 : 0xffffff800ac9d68a 
0xffffffa09549bea0 : 0xffffff800a5c5ed9 
0xffffffa09549bf90 : 0xffffff800aca141e 
0xffffffa09549bfa0 : 0xffffff800a43328f 

Process name corresponding to current thread: mds_stores

Mac OS version:
20E232

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.4.0: Fri Mar  5 01:14:14 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.101.1~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: BB2FFEBA-7D53-301F-A238-9867CA51276F
KernelCache slide: 0x000000000a200000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff800a400000
Kernel slide:      0x000000000a210000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff800a410000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800a300000
System model name: iMac17,1 (Mac-B809C3757DA9BB8D)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 87799808782
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x000000147146f503
  Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
  Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x00000005389dc118 0x0000000000000000
last started kext at 62756135304: @plugin.IOAVBDiscoveryPlugin  940.4 (addr 0xffffff7fa38d4000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4040.11
>AGPM   122
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    4.0.4
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    4.0.4
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.0.4
>!AMikeyDriver  283.15
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.2.9
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.2.9
>!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  283.15
>pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.4d18
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  1
>!AHDA  283.15
>!A!ISKLGraphics    16.0.2
>!A!ISKLGraphicsFramebuffer 16.0.2
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    8.0.4d18
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>AGDCBacklightControl   6.2.9
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>eficheck   1
@kext.AMD9000!C 4.0.4
|IO!BUSBDFU 8.0.4d18
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.100.11
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1677.100.114
>!ASDXC 1.9.0
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  11.0.0
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!AAHCIPort 346.100.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    311
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@plugin.IOAVBDiscoveryPlugin    940.4
>!AHIDKeyboard  224
>!AMultitouchDriver 4440.3
>!AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
>!AHS!BDriver   4040.11
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.4d18
@kext.triggers  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4070HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  4.0.4
>!UAudio    405.39
>!AGraphicsControl  6.2.9
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOAVB!F    940.4
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@!AGPUWrangler  6.2.9
|IOAccelerator!F2   442.9
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   8.0.4d18
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 8.0.4d18
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.4d18
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   5.0.3
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  585.1
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
@kext.AMDSupport    4.0.4
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.2.9
|IOGraphics!F   585.1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    980.4
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  290.7
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AXsanScheme   3
|IOAHCIBlock!S  332
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
|IOAHCI!F   294.100.1
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   980.4
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.4d18
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.4d18
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.101.1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.101.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.100.4
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.100.4
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

In another instance, I received the following report:

```
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000000c0a
 family: 6 model: 94 stepping: 3 microcode: 226
 signature: 0x506e3
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600 CPU @ 3.30GHz
 10 error-reporting banks
Processor 1: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC0_STATUS(0x401): 0xf600018000040150
 IA32_MC0_ADDR(0x402):   0x00007fff206f24f0
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out on cpu 0, NMI-ing
mp_kdp_enter() NMI pending on cpus: 0 1 2 3
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out during locked wait after NMI;expected 4 acks but received 1 after 2476132 loops in 1656000000 ticks
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80073c5ed9): "Machine Check at 0x00007fff206f24f9, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x00007ff87e4cc000, CR3: 0x0000000110b16174, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0\n" "RAX: 0x00007ff87e4c9000, RBX: 0x00007ff87e4c9000, RCX: 0x0000000000000020, RDX: 0x0000000000000be0\n" "RSP: 0x00007000097302c0, RBP: 0x00007000097302c0, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0x00007ff87e4cbfe0\n" "R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000000003, R10: 0x0000000000000003, R11: 0x0000000000000007\n" "R12: 0x0000000000003c00, R13: 0x000000000001a400, R14: 0x00007ff87be086a0, R15: 0x0000000000000001\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000202, RIP: 0x00007fff206f24f9, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/2288acc43c/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-7195.101.1/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa054013ba0 : 0xffffff800728e02d 
0xffffffa054013bf0 : 0xffffff80073d48e3 
0xffffffa054013c30 : 0xffffff80073c4eda 
0xffffffa054013c80 : 0xffffff8007232a2f 
0xffffffa054013ca0 : 0xffffff800728d84d 
0xffffffa054013dc0 : 0xffffff800728db43 
0xffffffa054013e30 : 0xffffff8007a9d68a 
0xffffffa054013ea0 : 0xffffff80073c5ed9 
0xffffffa054013f90 : 0xffffff8007aa141e 
0xffffffa054013fa0 : 0xffffff800723328f 

Process name corresponding to current thread: mdworker_shared

Mac OS version:
20E232

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.4.0: Fri Mar  5 01:14:14 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.101.1~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: BB2FFEBA-7D53-301F-A238-9867CA51276F
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000007000000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8007200000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000007010000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8007210000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8007100000
System model name: iMac17,1 (Mac-B809C3757DA9BB8D)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 118238759084
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x0000001b8794efd4
  Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
  Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000539f4bebe 0x0000000000000000
last started kext at 63645984894: @plugin.IOAVBDiscoveryPlugin  940.4 (addr 0xffffff7fa06d4000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4040.11
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   122
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
@fileutil   20.036.15
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    4.0.4
>!AMikeyDriver  283.15
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    4.0.4
>!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  283.15
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!AHDA  283.15
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.0.4
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    8.0.4d18
>AGDCBacklightControl   6.2.9
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>!A!ISKLGraphics    16.0.2
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.2.9
>!ASMCLMU   212
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.2.9
>pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.4d18
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  1
@kext.AMD9000!C 4.0.4
>!A!ISKLGraphicsFramebuffer 16.0.2
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>eficheck   1
|IO!BUSBDFU 8.0.4d18
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.100.11
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1677.100.114
>!ASDXC 1.9.0
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  11.0.0
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!AAHCIPort 346.100.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    311
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@plugin.IOAVBDiscoveryPlugin    940.4
>!AHIDKeyboard  224
>!AMultitouchDriver 4440.3
>!AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
>!AHS!BDriver   4040.11
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.4d18
@kext.triggers  1.0
>!UAudio    405.39
@kext.AMDRadeonX4070HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  4.0.4
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   8.0.4d18
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 8.0.4d18
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.4d18
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IONDRVSupport  585.1
>!AGraphicsControl  6.2.9
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOAVB!F    940.4
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    980.4
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.AMDSupport    4.0.4
|IOAccelerator!F2   442.9
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   5.0.3
@!AGPUWrangler  6.2.9
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.2.9
|IOGraphics!F   585.1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  290.7
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AXsanScheme   3
|IOAHCIBlock!S  332
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOAHCI!F   294.100.1
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   980.4
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.4d18
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.4d18
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.101.1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.101.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.100.4
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.100.4
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

Even during writing this question, my mac has crashed three times. The only peripherals I have on my machine is an HP LaserJet Pro MFP 126, my magic mouse and keyboard, and an ethernet connection to my modem.

I have tried reinstalling the OS several times. Can someone please help me figure out this problem?

Comment: Just got another crash, with `Process name corresponding to current thread: cfprefsd`.

Comment: First, I'd back up your data if you can, and run first aid on the disk in Disk Utility. Boot into the recovery partition if you have to.

Comment: Your Mac is an iMac late-2015.  Not iMac Pro. It is only a simple test, but have you run Apple Diagnostics (Hold down D at boot)?  At a guess, most likely hardware issue would be RAM and you can change the RAM easily - or just remove one stick at a time. Does the problem go away?

Comment: If software issue you need to erase before install of macOS. Then gradually reinstall other software and recover data (not settings) from your backup.

Comment: @Gilby: I'd start by restarting in Safe Mode to see if it's a third party issue. Personally, I was concerned about a disk failure in a sector that handles metadata (since both of the panic attacks listed mention spotlight daemons).

Comment: @TedWrigley I have my data backed up. I have tried running Disk Utility in recovery mode, but that did not reveal any problems. I have temporarily added my entire disk under privacy option in spotlight, and that seems to have stopped the panics? Haven't had a single crash in 24 hours.

Comment: @Gilby That did not reveal any problems either. I have tried a clean wipe of my disk and reinstalled macOS Big Sur. Still, that did not solve it. Adding the disk under spotlight seems to have fixed the issue? But I cannot be sure, and I cannot use spotlight now... Is there a better fix?

Comment: Ok, the next thing to try is to remove the disk from the privacy area in spotlight.  This should force spotlight to reindex the entire drive (which can take a few hours), but might fix the problem if all you had was a corrupted spotlight index. If that doesn't work, you can use `mdutil` in terminal to nuke the spotlight directory entirely and force the system to remark if from scratch. let me know if that's where you want to head, and I'll write an answer for it.

Comment: You have had kernel panics with at least 3 different frequently active processes. You have done erase and reinstall to no effect.  Makes it seem like hardware issue to me.  Most likely disk or RAM.

Comment: @Gilby I understand that, but won't that be detected in a Diagnostic Chech? (Pressing D while booting up). I did that and there were no issues found. If the RAM is faulty, I'll take the mac to a service center as soon as lockdown ends

Comment: @Ted Wrigley I think that will be a good idea. It has been almost two days without any crash, so I believe my issue is linked to spotlight/spotlight indexing. I'll appreciate an answer for this! :)

Comment: I just had another Kernel Panic. This time with a new process `xpcpproxy`. Here is the full log https://pastebin.com/xjLRf6dY

Comment: Another one, 5 mins ago. https://pastebin.com/zcbvW9D7
This one has the process as: kernel_task

Comment: Is this with spotlight still disabled?  If so, then I think it might be time for a trip to the genius bar so they can run diagnostics.

Comment: Apple Diagnostics (D when booting) will detect failed components.  It will not detect intermittent faults.

Comment: FYI: I found [this post on Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251802998?answerId=253462883022#253462883022) that explains how to completely delete the spotlight database and force it to re-index. In case it helps...

Comment: @TedWrigley Yep! Spotlight is still disabled. Sadly, I cannot take my mac to a service center because of the lockdown in my city. Are there any solutions I can explore online?

Comment: @Gilby I think I may have faulty RAM! I've run Android Studio for hours on an end, and it is a RAM monster. Could that have caused a problem that is not being detected in the Diagnostic test? If so, how can I be sure of it?

Comment: The diagnostic test only detects hardware that is not working. It only does a brief test of RAM. To sort a RAM problem (assuming that is your problem) there are two ways to test. A) Remove one of the RAM sticks (yours presumably has at least 2) and see if it works for some days with just one.  Then try with the other one. B) Run memory testing software. MemTest86 is free and can test RAM on a running macOS or (better) from a bootable USB flash drive.

Comment: Alright. I will give it a go! Thanks a lot :)